Using a loess smoothed variable with other predictors in linear regression
I am running an ordinary least squares regression analysis with 9 predictor variables, 2 numerical, 5 binary (1/0) and 2 categorical. One of my predictors (pred3) has an apparent non-linear relationship with the response as shown in the attached scatterplot. I fit a linear model without transforming any predictors and got an $R^2$ value of 0.57. I want a high $R^2$ value for my model. I want to avoid interaction terms if possible. In order to account for the non linear relationship of pred 3 and the resposne, I followed a suggestion of ChatGPT where I fit a loess smoothing model of the form pred3 ~ response, then used the loess predicted values of pred3 in the lm() model statement (see code snippet below). This resulted in an $R^2$ value of 0.95. However, I am not entirely sure if this is a valid way to predict my response. Does anyone agree with this idea or have any suggestions? I have tried using generalized additive models and polynomial models but they do not seem to improve my model fit. Please let me know!
loess_fit=loess(pred3 ~ response,data=data)
loess_pred3=predict(loess_fit)
model=lm(response ~ pred1+pred2+loess_pred3+pred4+pred5+pred6+pred7+pred8+pred9,data=data)


Just looking at the plot here, I think the real problem is the censoring that's apparent in your predictor. But anyways what I wanted to say is that using pred3 ~ response will treat the predictor as the response variable and it doesn't really make sense to compare that $R^2$ with your other model. There's really a lot going on here, so much that I think it's impossible to give you a good answer without more information about your research question, data, and code.

First, while wanting a high $R^2$ is fine, I don't think it should be your sole goal. For one thing, it would lead to models that are too complex. There are ways to adjust for this, the best known is probably adjusted $R^2$.
Second, avoiding interactions is not a good goal. If they are there in the populations, you should have them in your model.
Third, I wouldn't use ChatGPT to tell me how to do statistics; CrossValidated is MUCH better.
Finally, to the central point, a better way to model a nonlinear relation is with a spline of the variable itself (I suppose using a loess of the variable itself is roughly equivalent. You can do this in R fairly easily. Frank Harrell has written a lot about the details, both here on CV and in his book Regression Modeling Strategies.)
With any of these complex fits, you should consider validating your model, e.g. by dividing it into train and test (and possibly validate) sets. Lots has been written about this on here, too.

A different kind of comment is that "loess smoothed" is quite inadequate as a technical report, quite apart from concerns about its statistical validity.  Minimally, a report of the bandwidth and of how it was chosen is essential. Beyond that, loess is a broad family and several details of implementation vary between different software and different versions of the same software.  More crucially, this strategy will, if I understand correctly, often lead to inflated R-square and compromise any inferential results, e.g. confidence intervals and P-values.
